# android:excludeFromRecents="true" in manifest

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 3 Activities A, B, C.

In manifest.xml, A and B are secured with `android:excludeFromRecents="true"`.

```
A=Main Activity (secured)
B=Base activity (secured)
C=Extra activity (Less secured)
```

But, I want to show how many times the `Activity` C has appeared in recent launches in the app.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is add the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag when launching Activity C or some variation of that flag.

You can read some more on different ways of launching activities [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AcitivityC.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: the correct url you are trying to redirect people to is : https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html